# Asking for a date in PHP

Tags: php, html

When asking for a date in a HTML form, in the past I was using different solutions:

1. Using 3 different fields for day, month, year
2. Using a text field, but adding to the label something like "Start date (example: 31-12-2013)"
3. Using a reverse date, e.g. 2013-12-31

Now I would like to use HTML5, and just have a `input type='date'`. This should also help users with mobiles.

For some browsers this may offer a date picker, for some just a text fields. But we all know there are different date formats, and sometimes the user's machine is not configured as he/she would expect. For instance, if I enter a date of 3 January 2014 as 03-01-2014 this can be interpreted as 1 March 2014 in other cultures.

What is the best I can do to help users to prevent mistakes? Is there a way to write an example, without knowing in advance what are his/her browser settings? And how do I know that PHP will interpret the date correctly?

Comment: You could take a look at using javascript to validate the format, like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978631/how-to-set-date-format-in-html-date-input-tag) thread

Comment: There's simply no way to say whether `1/2/2014` is Jan 2nd or Feb 1st. HTML5 might be the breaking trend but good old calendar-based date pickers have always worked nicely.

Comment: keep the input textbox in readonly and use jquery datepicker to fill it

Comment: As far as I can see, Chrome shows (in my locale) dd-mm-yyyy, but submits it as yyyy-mm-dd. Besides Chrome, (partial) support is limited to Opera, iOS Safari, Android and Blackberry, see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: I just realized how ambiguous is my question  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use ISO 8601 (`YYYY-MM-DD`) + HTML5's `pattern` and `placeholder` attributes

An alternative to falling back to javascript datepickers, might be using a validation (regex) pattern as fallback for browsers that don't support the `date` type:

```
<input type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" name="date" value="" pattern="[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])" required="required">
```

While support for the [`date` input type](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) is still very limited, the [`pattern` attribute's support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation) is already more widespread. Of course you'll still need to check all submissions server side, but this should give a nice non-javascript solution for client side validation. You can use the `placeholder` attribute to show the right format, but since it's [not supported by older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder) (IE9 and lower) it might be better to display the example outside of the form field.

[html5pattern.com](http://html5pattern.com/) has a nice collection of ready-to-use input patterns, including [date](http://html5pattern.com/Dates) patterns but other ones as well. The benefit is that you can use the same pattern for your server side validation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Y-m-d is likely the best method, If you use jQuery UI's date picker you can specify the format.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

you can also show an alternative format.

Answer (score 1):

According to [dev.w3.org](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.date.html) it will supply you with "*A valid full-date as defined in [RFC 3339]*".
However there is no way to know what the user meant if they enter 1/2/2014, although 2014-02-01 is unambiguous). As others have mentioned, go with a date picker if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 date input specification specifies a full-date format equal to: yyyy-mm-dd. You will receive date in this format always.

[Follow this link for more information](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.date.html)