# html input type date input format as "dd/mm/yyy"

Tags: php, html, date, datepicker, date-format

I was designing form in php and html. For date i have used

```
In Date <input type="date" name="in_date" value="<?php  echo !empty($errors) ?  $_POST["in_date"] : date("Y-m-d"); ?>" />
```

In some pc it shows date in "dd/mm/yyyy" and in some it show "mm/dd/yyy" output for the above code in chrome browser. Is there any way in PHP & HTML I can fix input format to "dd/mm/yyyy".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `type="date"` means Chrome will try to display the date in accordance with the user's country/language settings. It's a feature, not a bug. If you really need to change the format, change the type to regular `text`.

Comment: it's worth mentioning that PHP assumes that `xx/xx/xxxx` is really `mm/dd/yyyy' - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format

Comment: I guess this question is about the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978631/how-to-set-date-format-in-html-date-input-tag

Comment: How do You obtain the value for `$_POST["in_date"]` ?

Comment: $_POST["in_date"] is used for filling data from user input before submitting form in case of any error.

Answer (score 0):

Using some jQuery datepicker plugins is better, such as:

1. [Eyecon](http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/)
2. [keith-wood](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.HTML)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for help. I got the answer.

We have to change setting of date format in client.
goto Control Panel > regional setting > Customize Button > Date Tab

enter Short Date Format as dd-MM-yyy 
Then come out by clicking OK button

Done!!!