# Input type=date format in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime, time

I use input type=date below to get datetime from screen in HTML. The input date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` but i wanna to change it to `dd/mm/yyyy`.

How can I do that?

```
<input type="date" value="' + today + '" 
       class="date" id="datePicker" style="width:30%" 
       min="25-10-1900" max="25-10-2100" />
```

PS: I also use that code below, but it doesn't work. (where should i call that function?)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#datePicker").mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "dd/MM/yyyy" });
});
```

Comment: Please see this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978631/how-to-set-date-format-in-html-date-input-tag

Comment: See this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format). There is no possible way of changing the format using HTML only.

Comment: A good number of browsers don't support input type date anyway.