# change format of input type="date"

Tags: html

i wrote like

```
  <input type="date" name="ex_date">
```

by default it will coming mm/dd/yyyy.Is it possible to change format of date to dd/mm/yyyy.Thanks in advance

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978631/how-to-set-date-format-in-html-date-input-tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)