# How to change the style and format of a date input on forms of HTML

Tags: html

In HTML forms, I'd like to know how to style the Date input and change the format(DD/MM/YYYy or MM-DD-YYYY)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set date format in HTML date input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978631/how-to-set-date-format-in-html-date-input-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can style your date elements using CSS:

```
.date .month{}
.date .day{}
```

[Here is an article that I found](https://www.gordonmac.com/styling-dates-with-css/)

[Follow this to learn about Datetime attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_time_datetime.asp)