# Replace default html5 date placeholder with custom text in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html

Currently the placeholder in Chrome is showing up as "Date/Month/Year", how do I enforce my own placeholder attributes?

```
<input type="date" name="date" value="" class="date" size="40" placeholder="Delivery Date (dd/mm/yy)*">
```

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968817/is-there-a-way-to-localize-input-type-date-in-html5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153492/html-5-input-type-date-formatting-on-ios

Comment: Also, this may help you: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder attribute [isn't supported](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html#input-type-attr-summary) on input elements for date-`type`.