# Using Knockout.js how do bind a Date property to a HTML5 date picker?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

*(this only works in Chrome at the moment as most browsers don't yet implement date picker for input type="date")*

In the following example MyDate starts out as a Date object with the current date, but this isn't picked up by the date input (which expects its format to be a string in format YYYY/MM/DD).

Once you've picked a date in the picker then MyDate becomes a string in format above.

How can you bind this so MyDate stays a javascript Date and is interpreted by the input control correctly?

See See http://jsfiddle.net/LLkC4/3/ :-

```
<input data-bind="value : MyDate" type="date">
<hr>   
<span data-bind="html: log" />

<script>
var viewModel = {    
    MyDate : ko.observable(new Date()),
    log : ko.observable(""),
    logDate : function () { 
            this.log(this.log() + this.MyDate() + " : " +
                     typeof(this.MyDate()) + "<br>");
                     }
};

viewModel.MyDate.subscribe(function (date) {    
    viewModel.logDate();    
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

viewModel.logDate()
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While @amakhrov answer will work (and would be even better if used writeable computed observable like sujested by @Stijn) I decided to do this using [Custom Bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

The main advantage of doing this is reusability - I just have to use `data-bind="datePicker : MyDate"` whereever I want to tie this in. I can also modify other properties of the input element so this could be really useful if binding to complex jQuery (and other) controls.

*([Read here for more pro/cons](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/reacting-to-changes-in-knockoutjs.html) about the 3 choices to do this sort of thing)*

HTML

```
<input data-bind="datePicker : MyDate" type="date">
```

JS

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datePicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {                    
        // Register change callbacks to update the model
        // if the control changes.       
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {            
            var value = valueAccessor();
            value(new Date(element.value));            
        });
    },
    // Update the control whenever the view model changes
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value =  valueAccessor();        
        element.value = value().toISOString();
    }
};

var viewModel = {    
    MyDate : ko.observable(new Date())
};     

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/LLkC4/5/

Comment: Is this still working for you?  My chrome datepicker refuses to show any date - just "mm/dd/yyyy" in the box even as I pick new dates and even as they show up in your log printout.  Do you know how to fix it?  I'm struggling.

Comment: @uosɐſ This wasn't working for me either until I started calling `ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())` in the update function.

Comment: Doesn't work, add viewModel.MyDate('2/2/2012'); to the bottom of the fiddle and see the date in the picker does not update.

Comment: Corrected answer for newish ko below

Answer (score 8):

You can use the computed vartiable for the date object in your model:

In html:

```
<input data-bind="value : rawDate" type="date">
```

In code:

```
var currentDate = (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0];

// this is used instead of MyDate in the data binding
rawDate : ko.observable(currentDate),

...
// and then set up the dependent variable
viewModel.MyDate = ko.computed(function () {
    var val = this.rawDate();
    if (typeof val === 'string') val = new Date(val);

    return val;
}, viewModel)
```

Please see the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gcAXB/1/

Comment: That doesn't set the value of the picker on initial load - suspect have to set rawDate to the ISO formatted string of MyDate?

Comment: YOu're right. The date was not displayed in your original example, so I forgot to add that as well :)
Please see the updated code and the demo above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you give me any idea about how to html5 datepicker (input type "date") with knockout.js without using computed variables? like it is done here: http://screencast.com/t/pMtuSV6mxUf

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that is working for me with the latest knockoutjs, based off of the link below and modified to have a custom init function to handle updating ko.computed properties as your date value changes.

Note that utils.formatDate is just a utility function to format the date in whatever string you want, so just replace that with your own date formatting code, whether you use momentjs or something else.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {    
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'change', function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();

            if (element.value !== null && element.value !== undefined && element.value.length > 0) {
                value(element.value);
            }
            else {
                value('');
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);

        var output = '';
        if (valueUnwrapped !== null && valueUnwrapped !== undefined && valueUnwrapped.length > 0) {
            output = utils.formatDate(valueUnwrapped);
        }

        if ($(element).is('input') === true) {
            $(element).val(output);
        } else {
            $(element).text(output);
        }
    }
};

    <div>
        <label>Date of Birth:</label>
        <input type="text" data-bind="date: dateOfBirth, format: 'DD MMM YYYY'" />
    </div>
```

[BINDING AND FORMATTING DATES USING KNOCKOUT AND MOMENT JS](http://jason-mitchell.com/web-development/binding-dates-using-knockout-moment-js/)

Comment: The link in post does not work, this is my code for MomentJS: http://www.cederlof.net/knockout-binding-to-javascript-dates-and-moment-formatting/

Comment: FYI for future knowledge, Jason Mitchell's article on this (link from above) is now at this [link](https://json.codes/blog/binding-and-formatting-dates-using-knockout-and-moment) (as of today)

Answer (score 5):

These days is so much easier with Moment.js

```
this.sessionDate = ko.observable(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
this.getFormattedDate = () => { return moment(this.sessionDate()'YYYY-MM-DD').format('MM/DD/YYYY') }; // Note this is ES2015 syntax
```

In your html you can bind it with

```
<input class="form-control" name="date" type="date" id="date" data-bind="value: sessionDate">
```

And display it formatted as

```
<p data-bind="text : getFormattedDate()">Loading Date</p>
```

No need to create custom bindings, and you can use a shim for older browsers.

Comment: I think this should be the new answer, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

The same as [this custom binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26940949/1011722), but using momentJS:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datePicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        // Register change callbacks to update the model
        // if the control changes.
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            value(moment(element.value).format());
        });
    },
    // Update the control whenever the view model changes
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value =  valueAccessor();
        element.value = moment(value()).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you tell me why when I changed format in update (like so: element.value = moment(value()).format("DD-MM-YYYY"); ) it updates my data in MM-DD-YYYY format?

Comment: Can you explain why 'update' still runs if we have a 'registerEventHandler'?

Comment: @petrosmm The update code gets triggered when the viewmodel value changes, whereas the event handler is fired when the DOM value changes e.g. by user input.

Answer (score 3):

Based off of Ryan's answer above, this works a little nicer with newer ko/chrome widgets.  It also strips the time part of the date.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datePicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        // Register change callbacks to update the model
        // if the control changes.
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var target_date = element.valueAsDate;
            var truncated = new Date(target_date.getFullYear(), target_date.getMonth(), target_date.getDate());
            value(truncated);
        });
    },
    // Update the control whenever the view model changes
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value =  valueAccessor();
        var unwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value());
        if(unwrapped === undefined || unwrapped === null) {
            element.value = '';
        } else {
            element.valueAsDate = unwrapped;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I had to use the blur event instead of the change event to make this work. Chrome 44.0.2403.39 beta-m (64-bit), knockout.js 3.10

Comment: As of 2/27/18 I'm not able to get this answer to work.

Answer (score 1):

From [HTML 5 - Input type date formatting on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153492/html-5-input-type-date-formatting-on-ios)

> There are two formats at play:
>
> - displayed format
> - internal format exposed to JavaScript and sent to the server
>
> You cannot change the display format. It's up to the browser to decide
>   how the date is presented to the user (in practice it's determined by
>   system's locale).
>
> You cannot change the internal format either. It's always ISO8601,
>   regardless of browser/locale.

You'll have to pre-populate it with that specific format, and you can add a computed observable to parse it into a `Date` object, so you can read it at other places in your application.

If you also want to write to it from JS, you could set up a [writeable computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) and parse the input to see if it's a string from the input field, or a `Date` object from your JS.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
ko.bindingHandlers.momentDate = {
_parseDateTime: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
    var datetime = moment(valueUnwrapped);
    var date = moment($(element).val(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    datetime = datetime.set({
        'year': date.get('year'),
        'month': date.get('month'),
        'date': date.get('date')
    });
    value(datetime.toDate());
},
init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    function bind() {
        ko.bindingHandlers.momentDate._parseDateTime(element, valueAccessor);
    }
    $(element).change(bind).blur(bind);
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
    var date = moment(valueUnwrapped);
    $(element).val(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
```

};

```
<input type="date" data-bind="momentDate: $data.Date" class="form-control"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably late but it might help someone out there. I'm using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/)'s `DateTime` object to easily manage dates and timezones in my application. This works with DateTime objects:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.dateTime = {
  // Register change callbacks to update the model if the control changes.
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'change', function () {
      const value = valueAccessor()
      const datetime = DateTime.fromFormat(element.value, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
      value(datetime)
    })
  },
  // Update the control whenever the view model changes
  update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    const value = valueAccessor()
    element.value = ko.unwrap(value).toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
// viewmodel
const today = DateTime.fromFormat(DateTime.now().toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
this.date = ko.observable(today)

// template
<input type="date" data-bind="dateTime: date">
```