# Show HH:MM in input type time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to use an html input field with the following code:

```
<td><input style="width: 80px" type="time" placeholder="HH:MM" required="" data-bind="value: FirstManifest"></td>
```

The backend C# object containing the FirstManifest property (DateTime?) is populated correctly but when I bind it to a knock view model, the property in the model FirstManifest looks like this

```
"/Date(1464748440000)/"
```

How can I convert this so my input only shows the datetime format HH:MM?

Comment: Can you write your C# code?  Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016718/using-knockout-js-how-do-bind-a-date-property-to-a-html5-date-picker#18058410  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how .NET serializes it DateTime i believe. You first need to convert it to JavaScript Date and then get the time element, e.g.

```
var manifest 
  = new Date(parseInt("/Date(1464748440000)/".replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));

this.FirstManifest = ko.computed(function() {
    return manifest.toLocaleTimeString();
}, this);
```

you will also need the `write` part of the computed to convert back from the input to date for persisting to the server.

- JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p02umbqL/

Answer (score 1):

It gets converted to milliseconds.Try converting it back like this.

```js
var oldDate= "/Date(1464748440000)/";
var newDate = new Date(parseInt(oldDate.substr(6)));
document.write(newDate);
```