# Set date in input type date

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date

I will set today's date in the datepicker input **type date** in Chrome.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let now = new Date();
    let today = now.getDate()  + '/' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + now.getFullYear();
    console.log(today);
    $('#datePicker').val(today);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="datePicker" type="date">
```

However, it is not working.

Please try the code snippet in Chrome.

Comment: If you pick a date on your fiddle and inspect the result frame, doing a `$('#datePicker').val();` gives `"2012-09-10"` and that's not the format you use for setting the date

Comment: It working in chrome on my end..
What do you exactly mean by `its not working`?

Comment: try : `{ currentText: "Now" }`,  see [manual](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-currentText)

Comment: working on me... what is the problem?

Comment: @RC, i will try `2012-09-10` this format but still not work.

Comment: `$('#datePicker').val("2012-09-01");` works for me

Comment: what is your computer's date time formate?

Comment: @JigarPandya fr_FR (@user108, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/3496622/180100)

Comment: my computer date formate `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: This [link](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome) states that chrome has changes policy after version 20; so if you are using newer version the above would fail perhaps. In that case you need to alter the logic in javascript to match your exact needs base on version of chrome. you can detect version using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/detect-version-of-browser

Comment: Please let me know the plugin you have used for the date picker. Probably trick can be done in the plugin... thanks

Comment: It works but your date has to be in this format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: you can use below date function
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
$("#datePicker").val(today);

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/7LXPq/93/

Two problems in this:

1. Date control in HTML 5 accepts in the format of Year - month - day as we use in SQL
2. If the month is 9, it needs to be set as 09 not 9 simply. So it applies for day field also.

Please follow the fiddle link for demo:

```
var now = new Date();

var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

$('#datePicker').val(today);
```

Comment: Post-2012 answer: check my answer for a supported solution in one line of code.

Comment: @OlivUtilo—sure, but your answer will deliver incorrect results some of the time.

Answer (score 181):

`document.getElementById("datePicker").valueAsDate = new Date()`

should work.

Comment: I've found that this doesn't work in Safari for some reason :(

Comment: Tested in Chrome and Edge & found working fine. As @Skipjack said, is awesome Answer !

Comment: Looks like the correct solution, however in Safari (13.1.2) the call gets you an Invalid State Exception. Not sure why...?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlinputelement_valueasdate

Comment: Thanks, date inputs are a huge pain and this is (now) the correct answer since Safari works as well.

Answer (score 39):

```
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
$("#datePicker").val(today);
```

Above code will work.

Comment: be warned the val() part of the input is local time while toISOString() outputs UCT-Time. Can result to the wrong date in or at least if using an input of type Date + Time will set the wrong hour.

Answer (score 28):

Update: I'm doing this with:

```js
date.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
```

Gives the same result as the accepted answer and has good support.

Comment: Works in safari

Comment: **Note:** this gives a date in the UTC time zone. In contrast the top answer uses local time.

Comment: @OlivUtilo—No, they do not for the period of the timezone offset for the host.

Comment: As Qwertie says, this potentially gives the wrong answer if you are using a date without a time. eg Sat Sep 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 gets converted to "2018-08-31"

Comment: [deleted previous comment for inaccuracy] so I'm thinking, time zone needs to be set on `date` then in this case (or forced to utc 0 before `toISOString`?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6777470/1140630 may be a good way to Date instance now in UTC

Comment: The UTC format of this answer is a huge problem and makes this one line answer... well not one-line anymore. You have to add or subtract hours depending on the GMT and light saving before converting toISOString

Answer (score 19):

to me the shortest way to solve this problem is to use moment.js and solve this problem in just 2 lines.

```
var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
$('#datePicker').val(today);
```

Comment: yeah just like $('#datePicker').val(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

Comment: For people unfamiliar with Moment, if you want to format an arbitrary Javascript Date object with moment(): 
`var yourFormattedDate= moment(yourDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');`
`$('#datePicker').val(yourFormattedDate);`

Comment: I would recommend against this. Downloading a library to do something relatively easy. But as of 2021 moment.js is a legacy project anyway

Answer (score 7):

Your code would have worked if it had been in this format: `YYYY-MM-DD`, this is the computer standard for date formats http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 5):

I usually create these two helper functions when using date inputs:

```
// date is expected to be a date object (e.g., new Date())
const dateToInput = date =>
  `${date.getFullYear()
  }-${('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
  }-${('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)
  }`;

// str is expected in yyyy-mm-dd format (e.g., "2017-03-14")
const inputToDate = str => new Date(str.split('-'));
```

You can then set the date input value as:

```
$('#datePicker').val(dateToInput(new Date()));
```

And retrieve the selected value like so

```
const dateVal = inputToDate($('#datePicker').val())
```

Comment: Really nice when I have multiple dates to adjust, and don't have moment.js on hand

Answer (score 5):

You can only use date in input `type="date"` as in format `YYYY-MM-DD`

I have implemented helper as `formatDate` in NODE.js express-handlebars, don't need to be worry ... just use format as described in first line.

e.g:

```
< input type="date" id="date" name="date" class="form-control" value="{{formatDate invoice.date 'YYYY-MM-DD'}}" />
```

Answer (score 5):

**2021**

A great way I found to do this is using locale for the formatting.  You can use it in many different ways. **This works for when you aren't using the jquery datepicker, but the html datepicker.**

```
  $("#datepickerEnd").val(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA'));//YYYY-MM-dd
```

Or split up for manipulation or adjustments or other uses.

```
let theDate = new Date();
  $("#datepickerEnd").val(theDate.toLocaleDateString('en-CA'));//YYYY-MM-dd
```

Manipulation example.

```
  theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate()-7);
  $("#datepickerStart").val(theDate.toLocaleDateString('en-CA'));//YYYY-MM-dd
```

The 'en-ca' is the needed format for my datepicker.  If yours is different you can look for a string format that matches.  Since it turns it to a string it does not contain extra information for messing up per region. So, in this way you can use it for purely formatting.

For more information

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Answer (score 2):

Datetimepicker always needs input format YYYY-MM-DD, it doesn't care about display format of your model, or about you local system datetime. But the output format of datetime picker is the your wanted (your local system). There is simple example in [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48193586/jquery-set-date-value-in-asp-net-core-2-razor).

Answer (score 2):

For me the shortest way to get locale date and in correct format for input `type="date"` is this :

```
var d = new Date(); 
var today = d.getFullYear()+"-"+("0"+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0"+d.getDate()).slice(-2);
```

Or this :

```
var d = new Date().toLocaleDateString().split('/');
var today = d[2]+"-"+("0"+d[0]).slice(-2)+"-"+("0"+d[1]).slice(-2);
```

Then just set the date input value :

```
$('#datePicker').val(today);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
$('#datePicker').val(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Note : You need to add Moment.js as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

A solution in one expression:

```
$('#datePicker').val(
    new Date()
    .toLocaleDateString("en-US", 
    {year:"numeric",month:"2-digit",day:"2-digit"})
   .replace(/(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/,"$3-$2-$1")
)
```

Answer (score -6):

**Jquery version**

```
var currentdate = new Date();

$('#DatePickerInputID').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd-M-y', currentdate));
```

Comment: `$.datepicker` is not default jQuery. You're using a plugin and without saying which one, this answer is useless.