# how can I get the value of a date input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, datepicker

I'm using an HTML input field of a date:

```
<input id="datepicker" type="date" value="11/12/2013" />
```

How can I get using JQuery the different values for the year, month and day?
each one need to be save as a different var

Thanks,

Comment: The value is just a string. Declaring `type="date"` doesn't cause it to be parsed automatically. jQuery has no functions for processing dates. You could try Moment.js, though.

Comment: There is [`valueAsDate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-valueasdate) though, but I haven’t checked how widely that is implemented …

Answer (score 2):

You can use split by `/` to get them in array individually:

```
var date=$('#datepicker').val().split('/');
var day=date[0];
var month=date[1];
var year=date[2];
```

Comment: It's alerting to me that the data is undefined... when I try to alert it

Comment: Can you share the fiddle??

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: For this to work you need to change type="text" OR you look at this post: [set date in input type date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346381/set-date-in-input-type-date)

```
   var d = $('#datepicker').val().split('/');
    var year = d[2];
    var month = d[1];
    var day = d[0];
```

Supposing you are using the DD/MM/YYYY format.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

Html:

```
<input id="datepicker" type="date" value="2013-11-11" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var date = $('#datepicker').val().split('-');
var year = date[2];
var month = date[1];
var day = date[0];
```

Note: type date take value in yyyy-mm-dd format

Answer (score 1):

With Javascript es6 you can do a one-liner

`let [day,month,year] = $('#datepicker').val().split('-');`