# Cannot assign value to date input in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `date` input control on my web page, and I cannot seem to be able to assign it a value in Chrome. This is my control:

```
<input type='date' id='dateDate' />
```

And I am assigning a value to it like this:

```
$('#dateDate').val('5/16/2018');
```

This works in IE, **but it is not working in Chrome**. Does anyone know why? Does Chrome handle `date` inputs differently now? Do I need to pass in an actual date object?

Below is a quick example. If you run it in IE, both fields are assigned properly. But if you run it Chrome, only the `text` input is assigned and **not** the `date` input.

```js
$('#assignDates').on('click', function(e){
    $('#textDate').val('5/16/2018');
    $('#dateDate').val('5/16/2018');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
input[type=text]: <input type='text' id='textDate' /><br/>
input[type=date]: <input type='date' id='dateDate' /><br/>
<input type='button' id='assignDates' value='Assign Dates' />
```

Comment: This answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346381/set-date-in-input-type-date basically the html5 date field accepts dates formated in iso YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: `$('#dateDate').val('05/16/2018');` ?

Comment: You're welcome.