# How to have javascript presets today's date in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date, getelementbyid

I am developing a project with Django.
I have an html webpage containing a form which has a date field.
I want javascript compile it with today's date as soon as my user lands on that webpage, so that he/she gets a kind of "default date".

I have in my html page (templates/aggiungi_terminologia.html), the date field:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="glossary_entry_input_21">Data di inserimento della terminologia</label>
    <small id="inputHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Compilare solo se è nota la data di pubblicazione del documento fonte, altrimenti inserire la data di oggi.</small>
    <input name="Data_inserimento_entry" type="date" value="01/01/1900" class="form-control" id="date_to_turn_into_today" placeholder="">              
</div>
```

and then the javascript call at the end of the form:

```
{% load static %} 
<script> src="{% static 'get_today_date.js' %}"</script>
```

And then, inside my javascript function (static/js/get_today_date.js):

```
var today = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
document.getElementById("date_to_turn_into_today").value = today;
```

and since I am using moment.js, I added 'moment' in **settings.py**> INSTALLED_APPS ,

and to install moment I run on my console:

```
pip install django-staticfiles-moment
```

But when I run the server, all I get on that field is this:

[image: date field of my HTML form]

My console is returning:

> WARNINGS: app_glossario.glossary_entry.Data_inserimento_entry:
>   (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
>           HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to
>   have the current date as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`

Why javascript is not replacing the date?
How can I make it work?
NOTE: the problem lies in the connection between js, html and django

Comment: There is something you are not showing. Do you load moment.js? Any errors in console? Errors in the network tab?

Comment: Can you copy/printscreen the console? There is probably an error in there (maybe you didn't format the date correctly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set date in input type date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346381/set-date-in-input-type-date)

Comment: @A.Meshu I think it is not, because my doubt is also on my other project settings. For example on my use of getElementById

Comment: please  check my answer

Comment: Another SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

Here is what I did.

In a javascript file called

> get_today_date.js

stored at path

> static/js/get_today_date.js

I inserted

```
function get_today_date() {
var now = new Date();
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
document.getElementById('date_to_turn_into_today').value = today;
}
```

as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57953522/7658051 .

Then in the HTML page, before the closing `</body>` tag, I inserted

```
{% load static %}

<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/get_today_date.js" %}></script>
<script> get_today_date() </script>
```

and it works perfectly.

There was no neet to install the module moment, and even if my console returns

> WARNINGS: app_glossario.glossary_entry.Data_inserimento_entry: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided. HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current date as default, use django.utils.timezone.now

my app works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Continue from comment about duplicated or not, take a look:

```js
var now = new Date();
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
document.getElementById('inputDate').value = today;
```

```html
<input type="date" id="inputDate" />
```

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript) also.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is not in the javascript function but in my connection between the js file and the html file

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar behavior (where the input field shows a date placeholder instead of my desired date) when I provided a date string that was incorrectly formatted. The input element seems to need a format like `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Here's a pretty intuitive solution using vanilla JS. The default value of the `input` element will be the (locale-specific) date.

(And most of the  further info you might want about JS Dates can be found [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Examples).)

```js
const
  // Selects input element 
  dateInput = document.getElementById("date"),

  // Defines Date object
  date = new Date(),

  // Extracts component parts of Date object
  year = date.getFullYear(),
  month = date.getMonth(),
  day = date.getDate(),

  // Defines a function to add a leading zero if needed
  pad = part => part < 10 ? "0" + part : part,

  // Formats date to meet the `input` element's expectations -- like: `yyyy-mm-dd`
  // (Adds +1 to month b/c `getMonth()` uses a zero-based array)
  dateString = year + "-" + pad(month + 1) + "-" + pad(day);

// Inserts date string into input element
dateInput.defaultValue = dateString;

// Repeats this process for the "time" parts
/*
const
  timeInput = document.getElementById("time"),
  hours = date.getHours(),
  minutes = date.getMinutes(),
  seconds = date.getSeconds(),
  timeString = pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(seconds);
timeInput.defaultValue = timeString;
*/
```

```html
<input id="date" type="date" />
<!--
  // Optional input for time
  <input id="time" type="time" />
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous code did not work just because I forgot to call the function in HTML, so I just had to add

get_today_date()

But in the end I am not sure if I correctly installed the moment module required for the previuos javascript script.