# Vue 3 Composition API, setting date input using the valueAsDate property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a date picker on my page which I initialize with today's date. Before porting to Vue I used:

```
document.getElementById("entryDate").valueAsDate = new Date()
```

*Courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13322910/2672848*

But this doesn't work for me in Vue. Obviously I need to access the element itself to get the `valueAsDate` property, so I do:

```
const entryDate = ref(null)
const entryDateElem = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  entryDateElem.value.valueAsDate = new Date()
})
```

and in my template:

```
<input type="date" ref="entryDateElem" v-model="entryDate"></input>
```

but the date picker value is unchanged. If I use the alternate answer in that same Stack Overflow post (setting the value directly) it does work, as expected.

```
onMounted(() => {
  entryDate.value = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)
})
```

But why doesn't `valueAsDate` work? I have checked that entryDateElem.value refers to the element in question.

Comment: Your `valueAsDate` code works fine in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-v-model-in-vue-3-zy1un?file=/src/App.vue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vue it's not recommended to manipulate the DOM using vanilla JS because Vue is data-driven framework which means that your input should be bound to a data property and it changes based on that data not by assigning raw data to its attributes like :

```
entryDateElem.value.valueAsDate = new Date() // you're manipulating directly the DOM ❌
```

the right way :

```
entryDate.value = new Date() // you're manipulating the data ✔
```

Comment: entryDate.value = new Date() does not work, but entryDate.value = "YYYYMMDD" does. Not sure what the issue was for me