# Establish as default value of an input data type DATE from the db

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

i want to create a edit form in my project but when i try to set the old values i cant with the date value, is empty.
(i'm working with mysql, Js and this form is in handlebars)

This is the route:

```
router.get('/edit/:id', async(req,res)=>{    
     const { id }=req.params;     
     const casos = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM casos WHERE id=?',[id]);     
      res.render('casos/edit',{casos:casos[0]}); });
```

i tried something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">  
  <label>Fecha de cirugía</label>  
   <input type="date" value="{{casos.fechacirugia}}" class="form-control" name="fechacirugia"/>  
</div>
```

I want to get a input with the db value

Comment: You're missing the comma before `[id]`.

Comment: What do you see in the `value=""` if you do `View Source`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set date in input type date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346381/set-date-in-input-type-date)

Comment: The date must be in yyyy-MM-dd format (i.e., 2023-07-11)

Answer (score 0):

try this instead the ternary operator to set the default key

```
<input type="date" value="{{casos.fechacirugia? casos.fechacirugia: 'default_value'}}" class="form-control" name="fechacirugia"/>
```

Comment: thank u!,
i tried, but...  
Error: Missing helper: "casos.fechacirugia?"