# I accepted DOB as a string and tried to convert it to DATE TIME But It gives me error

Tags: c#, html

I have A html page from where i am sending many data to handler this is a part of my handler

```
string dob = (context.Request.QueryString["dob"]);
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dob, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

here dob contains date of birth in format like 03/25/1993.
But while debugging it gives an error
"the datetime represented by the string is not supported in calendar system.globalization". 
EDIT- If i enter 09/09/2014 it gives no error.
.[image: error MSG]

Comment: use `TryParse` instead of `ParseExact`

Answer (score 2):

You specify the format

> "dd/MM/yyyy"

and provide data

> 03/25/1993

25 is not a valid month.

**UPDATE**

Your comment:

> The problem persist, In CHROME when i am using input type = date, it is accepting value in format of mm/dd/yyyy but when it is reaching to handler it is in format yyyy-mm-dd. Its Working fine in IE

According to [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#page-6), Chrome's behavior is correct.  The browser is supposed to offer an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date.  Wonderful to see that IE is still creating browser inconsistencies.

Have a look at the accepted answer for

[Handling browser-specific support of HTML input type="date"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738510/handling-browser-specific-support-of-html-input-type-date)

for solving this inconsistency.

Comment: The problem persist, In CHROME when i am using input type = date, it is accepting value in format of mm/dd/yyyy but when it is reaching to handler it is in format yyyy-mm-dd. Its Working fine in IE