# Birthday field doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I need a birthday field with format "0000/00/00". I have one field with format "MM/DD/YYYY" but doesn't work in MySQL when I insert something.

There is the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="birthDate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date of Birth</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
       <input type="date" id="birthDate" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set date format in HTML date input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978631/how-to-set-date-format-in-html-date-input-tag)

Comment: where's your insert code? Also - phpmyadmin is irrelvant - data enters mysql the same way no matter your prefered mysql ui

Comment: I think your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496241/specifying-the-value-output-of-of-an-html5-input-type-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `datetime` format i.e. `MM/DD/YYYY` is different from the mysql default format. The default format is:

```
Y-m-d H:i:s
```

So change it to like:

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime($yourDate));
```